# Desaparece valor de variable de captura de buffer

Tags: php, html

Capturando el contenido del buffer en una variable,

```html
<?php
ob_start(); 
echo "Texto capturado";
$variable = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean(); 
echo $variable;
```

posteriormente la variable `$variable` pierde el valor, y no entiendo el porqué. Si quiero utilizar el valor de `$variable` después del `echo`no me muestra nada (esta vacio)

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: De donde sale la variable `$salida`?

Comment: La variable salida no la veo definida

Comment: Ya he corregido el codigo que tenía un error al incluirlo en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que tienes mal es un fallo de concepto, el código esta bien. Míralo de esta manera, a ver si así se entiende que el primer echo no es el que escribe

```
<?php
ob_start();

echo "Texto capturado";
$variable = ob_get_contents(); 
ob_end_clean(); 

echo "CAPTURADO => ".$variable." => FIN";
```

Comment: Entonces, como tengo que proceder para usar el valor de `$variable` por ejemplo en una consulta de mysql, porque la variable existe pero vacía. ¿no se puede conservar el valor?

Comment: Ya lo hace http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2a067878e76ac211d0025d797f9e3745b2e70fe1

Comment: En efecto, tienes razón. He detectado mi problema, y es del origen del texto capturado, que en mi caso viene de una funcion ajax con una query a mysql. Muchas gracias por la aclaracion.